# how to unselect all elements in a primefaces selectCheckboxMenu from commandbutton

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I've been trying to achieve this but no avail.

tried :

```
scmWidgetVar.clear();
```

but no avail, is there any out of box javascript function that does this job ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clear the bean field's value related to your component.

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{formBean.values}" widgetVar="var" ... />

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{formBean.resetValues}" update="@widgetVar(var)" value="Reset"/>
```

Your bean :

```
... 
private List<String> values;

public void resetValues()
{
values.clear();
}
...
```